# NodeJS Winston not writing in the log file

Tags: node.js, winston

I'm trying to use Winston to create logs, but it is not writing in the file.

I have the following file in controllers/myControler/myFile.js

```
const path = require('path');

const winston = require('winston');
const filename = path.join(__dirname, 'testLog.log');
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({ filename, level: 'error' })
    ]
});

exports.test = async (req, res, next) => {
   logger.log({
      level: 'error',
      message: 'Test'
   });
}
```

I have the file testLog.log in the root of my project.

When I run the application, I can see in the terminal:

```
{"level":"error","message":"Test"}
```

However, the testLog.log file still empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new winston.transports.Console` does not accept `filename` option.

You have to append `File` transport for your `logger`.

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({ level: 'error' }),
    // new line
    new winston.transports.File({ filename, level: 'error' }),
  ]
});
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you!